# Primefaces inside dynamic jsf fragment not working

Tags: ajax, jsf, dynamic, primefaces, fragment

I have a dynamically rendered jsf fragment which has an date element which on selection is supposed to perform logic in my request scoped bean but it never fires.

When I take the element out of the fragment it works fine.

```
<p:calendar id="dob_calendar"
    value="#{registrationDetailsHandler.dateOfBirth}"
    showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" yearRange="c-80:c+1"
    required="true" 
    requiredMessage="Date of Birth is Required"
    immediate="true">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="kid_panel"
        listener="#{registrationDetailsHandler.calculateAge()}"
        process="@this,firstName" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: Try changing your managed scope to `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: When I make it @ViewScope none of my ajax is working.  This is in a composite.

Comment: Any other info to get down to the real situation to find the problem?

Comment: Where is your fragment?

Comment: Just in case!
Is this in an h:form ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use class name instead of id, and use jQuery selector

Eg

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="kid_panel">
```

And in your dynamic block

update="@(.kid_panel)" or process="@(.kid_panel)"